# ie9 css issue with tbody width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

In IE9 the width doesn't seem to be getting applied to my tbody see below and in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kt3X2/)

```
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="l_name">Name</label>:</td>
    <td class="value"><input type="text" name="l_name" value="" id="l_name"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <style>
        table {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        tbody {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 360px;
        }
    </style>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using valid doctype like **`<!DOCTYPE HTML>`**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<style>
table {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        tbody {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 360px;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, the fiddle I have and the test site I have on my localhost have this already